# Formatting postcodes / zip codes

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides, customer-address, address, format

When a customer adds a postcode / zip code I would like to complete some PHP formatting.

From what I can see there are 3 places were a customer can add an address with a postcode

1. Signup
2. My Account Address Book
3. OnePage Checkout

For Signup I can see I can override the Mage_Customer_AccountController

For the My Account Address Book I can see I can override the Mage_Customer_AddressController

However For the OnePage Checkout I can seem to find where the logic is for adding an address. Please could someone advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a**pp/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/Onepagecontroller.php**

Mage_Checkout_OnepageController there are saveBillingAction() and saveShippingAction() functions. have below code

```
$this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
```

so you need to rewrite Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage in file:

**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php** below function

public function saveBilling() and public function saveShipping()